# How to get customer ID in Collection _initSelect method in magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, join-table

I want customerId in `_initselect` method. How can I achieve this ?

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['cp1' => $this->getTable('2checkout_ins')],
        'cp1.id =main_table.two_checkout_message_id OR cp1.id = NULL',
        ['main_table.increment_id','main_table.from_date','main_table.subscription_period','main_table.to_date','main_table.renew_date','main_table.status_success','main_table.customer_id','main_table.paypal_id','main_table.two_checkout_message_id','final_amount'=>'cp1.invoice_usd_amount']
        )->joinLeft(
        ['cp2' => $this->getTable('paypal_result')],
        'main_table.paypal_id = cp2.id OR cp2.id = NULL',
        ['final_amount_paypal'=>'cp2.amount']
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

PLease check below Image:
[image]

Comment: please elaborate more where you want customer id is this your custom code or magento code, if it is magento code then write filename and also clarify do you want login customer id ?

Comment: I want customerId in customer edit page in my custom listing page

Comment: in admin customer edit page right?

Comment: yes,  right@PrashantValanda

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');` You can get ID by this code in Controller.

Comment: I want customerID in model to display my custom grid in customer edit page uding tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\Magento\Backend\Model\SessionFactory $adminsession`
and get

```
$admin =  $this->adminsession->create();
$customerData=$admin->getData();
return $customerData['customer_data']['customer_id'];
```